# REST Api и внутренняя работа приложения

Tags: rest

Как я понял, REST Api это внешний интерфейс для работы с данными. А как осуществляется работа внутри приложения? Обращаться из кода по внешней ссылке за порцией данных вместо прямого обращения к БД, на мой взгляд, глупая идея.

Тряпками не кидайтесь, если вопрос тупой, я всего лишь в начале пути.

Скажем, для того что вывести список на странице, мы делаем get запрос

`api/users`

который нам возвращает json. А внутри приложения как оно происходит? Может, нужно просто метод обращаться к методу на "его языке"? Вроде этого:

`$users->get('users')`

Comment: Честно говоря, за последние дни столько всего перечитал, что каша в голове. Может, кто тут несколько уроков даст (можно и не бесплатно), можно и по скайпу, м?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST это для клиент-серверных приложений. Есть бэкенд и фронтенд, где первый как раз определяет REST сервис, а второй делает отображение.

Вот в пример: у меня есть сайт и мобильное приложение, а есть сервер с бд. Так вот сайт и приложение являются представлением данных и каждый делает это по-своему но оба основываясь на данных, которые отдает сервис, который напрямую связан с БД.

Если приложение построено на моделях (entities), что есть гуд, тогда код будет примерно такой

```
$users = UserRepository::find()->where('role'=>'online_access');
```

Но может выглядеть и по-другому, в зависимости от того, какова архитектура, и пр. В общем суть такова, что бэкенд работает с бд и данными, затем приводит их к какому-то виду.

UPD. Вот тебе пример рабочего метода из REST-сервиса

```
/**
 * All
 * Lists all Users (available for roles with code LIST_ACCESS)
 *
 * @throws EmptyResponseException If no user was found
 * @throws ForbiddenHttpException If role code LIST_ACCESS not available
 *
 * @return array of users
 */
public function actionAll()
{
    /** @var User $user to find */
    $user = User::findOne(
        [
            'token' => $this->getToken()
        ]
    );

    /** If no data was fetched */
    if (is_null($user)) {
        throw new EmptyResponseException;
    }

    /** @var Role $role of fetched user so we can decide, is that page available or not */
    $role = $user->getRole();
    /** Check section access to view other profiles */
    if (!$role->hasSectionAccess(self::LIST_ACCESS)) {
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException("Access denied for this user");
    }

    /** Fetch all users */

    return $this->response(User::find()->all());
}
```

Comment: Это понятно. Непонятно другое. Допустим два случая: вам нужен список для представления, и тот же список для каких-то манипуляций внутри кода. Я буду прав, если скажу, что дублировать два одинаковых запроса к БД не имеет смысла? 

Тогда, если есть внешний интерфейс для получения данных, на который завязаны обращения к БД, то как эти такие же обращения будут реализованы в коде приложения?

Несколько дней уже читаю про rest, и каждый раз примеры касаются только внешнего интерфейса, а о внутренней работе ни слова. ((

Comment: @hcuser, смотри. Абстрагируйся от запросов. Допустим, у нас есть таблица `users`. Тогда мы создаем класс `User`, в котором свойства - аттрибуты таблицы. Например, `users - id | name`, тогда класс `class User { public $id; public $name;}`, который является `Entity`. Многие ORM умеют создавать это сами, а некоторые могу из классов делать структуру БД.

И дальше у тебя уже не будет запросов как таковых. Ты будешь писать код, как в ответе, не используя sql в коде. Почитай: 
[doctrine][1]


  [1]: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#starting-with-the-produc

Comment: Ну, исходя из примера выше и того, что сказано сейчас, в сущности так и получается. За обработку запросов через внешний интерфейс и запросов из кода отвечают, в конечном итоге, одни и те же функции. Только в случае с rest api есть посредник, который разбирает URI, обращается к БД за результатом, преобразует его в JSON, XML или во что-то другое, что запросил пользователь. Верно?

По поводу БД. Сейчас у меня по старинке всё, голые запросы. Я так понимаю, использовать doctrine, PHP PDO или что-нибудь аналогичное по смыслу — дело вкуса?

Comment: @hcuser

1. "внизу" должен лежать PDO. Просто потому, что это абстрагирование от движка БД.
2. Doctrine, различные реализации ActiveRecord - это высокоуровневая оболочка, внутри которой все равно лежит PDO.